# Microsoft Media Foundation in Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi as I am using NAudio tools to convert mp3 files to wav, I need to have Microsoft Media Foundation installed on target hosting machine. However the servers on the backend of Azure Web App does not have Media Foundation installed. Please is there any way how to enable it? I do not want to end up with virtual machines...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please is there any way how to enable it? I do not want to end up with virtual machines

I haven't found any way to do it. I suggest you try any other way to convert mp3 to wav without depending Microsoft Media Foundation.

FFmpeg is a workaround for you. Steps below are for your reference.

1. Download the Windows build of it from following site.

[Download FFmpeg for Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

2. Extract the package and copy 'ffmpeg.exe' file to your project. For example, copy this file to the bin folder of your web application.
3. Install ffmpeg .NET wrapper package. There are many .NET wrapper for ffmpeg on web. On my side, I use [MediaToolkit](https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolkit). You could install it from NuGet by searching 'MediaToolkit'.
4. Convert mp3 to wav using following code.

```
var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = Server.MapPath(@"/Content/testmp3.mp3") };
var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = Server.MapPath(@"/Content/testwav.wav") };

using (var engine = new Engine(Server.MapPath(@"/bin/ffmpeg.exe")))
{
    engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
}
```

5. After deployed your web application to Azure Web App, you need to copy the 'ffmpeg.exe' file to the bin folder of your Azure Web App manually.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Webjob to handle all conversion processing at the background